# MongoDB specific field find is not working

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, ecmascript-6, find

I have found a solution to find a specific field. But it's not working on my Meteor app. I am tried to find only the `location` field but it returns me all.

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.eventsTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
        let subscription = Meteor.subscribe("events");
        let eventsArray = Events.find({}, { location: 1 }).fetch();
        console.log("eventsArray", eventsArray);
        const distinctArray = _.uniq(eventsArray, false, function(d) {
            return d.location;
        });
        const disctinctValues = _.pluck(distinctArray, "location");
        this.setState({
            locations: disctinctValues,
            isLoading: !subscription.ready()
        });
    });
}
```

[image: console]

Comment: Meteor requires the `fields` name in the options to use for projection. i.e `Events.find({}, { fields: { location: 1 } })`. Note also MongoDB **always** returns `_id` unless you also include `_id: 0` in that projection.

Comment: @NeilLunn I want to know a thing. finding specific field is faster than all fields find?

Comment: It really depends on your data. Certainly if each document has 100's of properties then if you only need one of those it's faster to actually just return that one. If it's just 4-5 properties it probably costs more for the query engine to remove the properties than it does to transport across the network. Unless of course it's a "covered query". Too many variables for a "general" answer.

Comment: `const gallery = Gallery.find(
                { userID: Meteor.userId() },
                {
                    fields: { _id: 1, projectImage: 1, projectVideo: 0 }
                },
                { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit: Session.get("eventLimit") }
            ).fetch({});` @NeilLunn Could you see this? it's not working. Maybe syntex probelm

Comment: [Project Fields to Return from Query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). You cannot mix "inclusion" and "exclusion" with the exception of `_id: 0`. If you have further questions then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead, where you can clearly describe details.